# Aggregate SQL query on tables with column with same name

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I have two tables, both with a column called `transaction_amnt`. Is there a way I can write a SQL query that returns the sum of all of the transaction amounts in both tables? I tried

```
select sum(transaction_amnt) from table1 natural join table2;
```

but, I'm thinking that `join` isn't really what I want here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `union all` best fits to your question as it will not remove duplicates on the records.

```
SELECT SUM(x.transaction_amnt) totalAmount
FROM
(
    SELECT transaction_amnt from table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT transaction_amnt from table2
) x
```

Answer (score 0):

As you did not show us your table definition it is not clear to me what you really want, but this might what I think you are looking for:

```
select sum(transaction_amnt) 
from (
  select transaction_amnt
  from table1 
  union 
  select transaction_amnt
  from table2
) t
```

Comment: @JohnWoo: correct. As the initial question is unclear, we don't know what Daniel wants